# Sum of bytes of database files of oracle database is showing more than the physical used size of the mount point

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle-11g

We are having oracle 11g2 database on Solaris 10. We have all data files under single mount point say /u001 and we make the sum of bytes of all data files which is more than the physical used size of mount point /u001 Please suggest is this possible? 
Below is the 
All data files are under mount point /u001

```
select sum (bytes)/1024/1024/1024 from dba_data_files 
204 GB
```

And the physical size of the mount point is

```
df- h /u001 
            size   used    avil    capacity mounted on  
####/u001   685G   67G     531G     12%     /u001
```

Please do suggest is this possible

Comment: Are you sure all data files are located at /u01? Is there an /u02?

Comment: Yes that is what i am wondering  for the results.Do i need to check for the fragmentation

Comment: I am just wondering... do you use sparse files? What is the storage-backend for /u01?

Comment: Show the whole output of `select file_name, file_id, bytes from dba_data_files;`, please.

Comment: Hi its big output i can not put her due to security issue. how do i find sparse files?

Comment: How on earth should the name of your datafiles be a security issue? But you can always sanitize your filenames if you need to, but the mount point should not be any issue at all if you even ask a question about it.

Comment: Hi  please find the below output

Comment: Please edit such information into your question rather than posting it as a comment. Your output sums up to 43GB

Comment: SQL> select file_name, file_id, bytes from dba_data_files;
/u001/oradata/DB_name/data-366836382_TS-SYSTEM_FNO-1_0dq2o6s0
         1                                                                                                    
     3.2212E+10
/u001/oradata/DB_name/data-366836382_TS-SYSAUX_FNO-2_14q2o82p
        2                                                                                                
        3221225472

Comment: There is constraint while putting the out put of the query so i have put only two files

Comment: Edit the output INTO you question, not as a comment: https://serverfault.com/posts/984835/edit